# Why is typeof Object,String,Number... -a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

Below is excerpt from Google Developer Console

```
typeof Object  // type of Object is function (most confusing part).
"function"      //Same fot all build-in types

Object.constructor 
function Function(){[native code]}// Why not function Object()?

Object.hasOwnProperty("create")  // Here, it is Object since it has property,not typeof      
"true"                              function


dir(Object) // Again, Object is object,it has property (method)
function Object() { [native code] }
```

Why typeof Object is not Object ? And why Object.constructor is not a function Object() ?

Thank you
MIro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identifiers `Object`, `String`, etc are not "class names" as you might have seen in other languages.  Nor are they *instances* of the specific type.

`Object` on its own is the *constructor* for an "Object", i.e. a reference to a function.

To further complicate matters, Javascript functions are also objects, which may have properties.  Those properties are often used to add *methods* to objects.